# Get the index of selected text using JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

How to get the index of selected text using `JEditorPane`?

I am trying to get the starting and ending index of selected text in editor pane.

When I select the text in editor pane,  the index returned by editor pane is different from the index of string in actual HTML file. When I select  a single line text then both indexes are same but if I select multiple line then indexes are different.

I am using the following code.

```
int start = editorpane.getSelectionStart();
int end = editorpane.getSelectionEnd();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Start index "+ start);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "End index "+end);
```

It return smaller index.

when using the following code its returning the actual index but i want   the same index in   above code.

```
 try
   {
    File f1= new File("path of the file");
    FileReader fin= new FileReader(f1);
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fin);
    String s=br.readLine();
    String con="";
    while(s!=null)
    {
    con=con+s;
    s=br.readLine();

    }
    int l=con.lastIndexOf("CASE CITED");

    System.out.println("index="+l);


   }
   catch(Exception ex){}

}
```

Comment: You said in your last question you'd 'take care of' adding upper case letters where needed.  This question shows no sign of that, and is even worse. -1 to both questions.

Comment: where is the uppercase needed in this question

Comment: Try looking at the [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16585264/revisions)!

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow.

Comment: *"I am new in stackoverflow."*  That is why I try to explain these things.  But that is **not** sufficient excuse when I've already tried explaining, and you failed to mention *"I don't understand what you mean by ...."*.

Answer (score 3):

Use `editorpane.getSelectionStart()/getSelectionEnd()`

Comment: this returns the index of editor pane but i want the index according to html files showing in editor pane.

Comment: What is the "index according to html files"?

Comment: html file index returns the actual index of the string including html tags. but it doesnt do so.

Comment: "it doesn't do" means nothing. Is returned index bigger/smaller/-1/exception? Provide SSCCE to show the problem.